# Need to put UVM reg model handles in an array

Tags: system-verilog, verification, uvm

I'm trying to combine the register block handles into an array so that I can access them using an index.

For example lets say I have the below register class :

```
class ral_sys_traffic extends uvm_reg_block;
  rand ral_block_traffic_cfg1 cfg_1;
  rand ral_block_traffic_cfg2 cfg_2;

    `uvm_object_utils(ral_sys_traffic)
    function new(string name = "traffic");
      super.new(name);
    endfunction

    function void build();
      this.default_map = create_map("", 0, 4, UVM_LITTLE_ENDIAN, 0);
      this.cfg1 = ral_block_traffic_cfg1::type_id::create("cfg1",,get_full_name());
      this.cfg1.configure(this, "");
      this.cfg1.build();
      this.default_map.add_submap(this.cfg1.default_map, `UVM_REG_ADDR_WIDTH'hF4402000);
      this.cfg2 = ral_block_traffic_cfg2::type_id::create("cfg2",,get_full_name());
      this.cfg2.configure(this, "");
      this.cfg2.build();
      this.default_map.add_submap(this.cfg2.default_map, `UVM_REG_ADDR_WIDTH'hF4403000);
    endfunction

endclass
```

I will have to access the registers with something like this:

```
regs.cfg_1.REG1_EN....
regs.cfg_2.REG1_EN....
```

However, I want to keep both the register blocks in an array so that I can do something like :

```
regs.cfg[0].REG1_EN...
regs.cfg[1].REG1_EN...
```

To accomplish this, I modified my code as follows:

```
class ral_sys_traffic extends uvm_reg_block;
  //rand ral_block_traffic_cfg1 cfg_1;
  //rand ral_block_traffic_cfg2 cfg_2;
  uvm_reg_block ral_cfg[];

    `uvm_object_utils(ral_sys_traffic)
    function new(string name = "traffic");
      super.new(name);
      ral_cfg = new[2];
    endfunction

    function void build();
      this.default_map = create_map("", 0, 4, UVM_LITTLE_ENDIAN, 0);
      this.ral_cfg[0] = ral_block_traffic_cfg1::type_id::create("ral_cfg[0]",,get_full_name());
      this.ral_cfg[0].configure(this, "");
      this.ral_cfg[0].build();
      this.default_map.add_submap(this.ral_cfg[0].default_map, `UVM_REG_ADDR_WIDTH'hF4402000);
      this.ral_cfg[1] = ral_block_traffic_cfg2::type_id::create("ral_cfg[1]",,get_full_name());
      this.ral_cfg[1].configure(this, "");
      this.ral_cfg[1].build();
      this.default_map.add_submap(this.cfg2.default_map, `UVM_REG_ADDR_WIDTH'hF4403000);
    endfunction

endclass
```

`ral_block_traffic_cfg1` and `ral_block_traffic_cfg2` classes extend from `uvm_reg_block` class.

The above code is throwing an error at

> this.ral_cfg[0].build();

saying that *"build is not a class item"* and there is no error at:

> this.ral_cfg[0].configure(this, '');

The original source is in the EDA playground here : edaplayground.com/x/4Xab

Is there any way around this issue or any other workarounds?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT : made modification to the edaplayground link for more accurate representation of the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of `ral_block_traffic_cfg` objects:

```
  rand ral_block_traffic_cfg cfg [2];
```

You created an array of type `uvm_reg_block`, named it `ral_cfg`, but it has nothing to do with the `ral_block_traffic_cfg` object.

Then, inside the `build` function, use this:

```
    function void build();
      this.default_map = create_map("", 0, 4, UVM_LITTLE_ENDIAN, 0);
      this.cfg[0] = ral_block_traffic_cfg::type_id::create("cfg[0]",,get_full_name());
      this.cfg[1] = ral_block_traffic_cfg::type_id::create("cfg[1]",,get_full_name());
      this.cfg[0].configure(this, null);
      this.cfg[1].configure(this, null);
      this.cfg[0].build();
      this.cfg[1].build();
```

Comment: There is no `ral_block_traffic_cfg` object in the RAL model. `ral_block_traffic_cfg1` and `ral_block_traffic_cfg2` are two different types.
And `ral_block_traffic_cfg1` and `ral_block_traffic_cfg2` extend from `uvm_reg_block` so since this is the parent type, I created an array of this type

Answer (score -1):

It is because uvm_reg_block class is extended from uvm_object and build is not a function in uvm_reg_block class.

Check details on https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/reg/uvm_reg_block-svh.html

Comment: thanks for answering! It would be helpful to expand this answer with a code sample or quote from the documentation showing how to achieve what the questioner was trying to accomplish. In general, just including a link to the documentation without a code sample or quote is discouraged, because links can break, change, or get out of date.